# python crontab alternative - APScheduler & python-daemon

Tags: python, scheduler, python-daemon

I'm having trouble using 
[python-daemon 1.6](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/1.6) getting along with APScheduler to manage a list of tasks.

(The scheduler needs to run them  periodically at a specific chosen times - seconds resolution)

**Working (until pressing Ctrl+C),**

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import logging
import signal

def job_function():
    print "Hello World"

def init_schedule():
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
        sched = Scheduler()
        # Start the scheduler
        sched.start()

        return sched

def schedule_job(sched, function, periodicity, start_time):
        sched.add_interval_job(job_function, seconds=periodicity, start_date=start_time)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sched = init_schedule()
    schedule_job(sched, job_function, 120, '2011-10-06 12:30:09')
    schedule_job(sched, job_function, 120, '2011-10-06 12:31:03')

    # APSScheduler.Scheduler only works until the main thread exits
    signal.pause()
    # Or
    #time.sleep(300)
```

**Sample Output:**

INFO:apscheduler.threadpool:Started thread pool with 0 core threads and 20 maximum threads
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Scheduler started
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:Looking for jobs to run
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:No jobs; waiting until a job is added
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Added job "job_function (trigger: interval[0:00:30], next run at: 2011-10-06 18:30:39)" to job store "default"
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Added job "job_function (trigger: interval[0:00:30], next run at: 2011-10-06 18:30:33)" to job store "default"
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:Looking for jobs to run
DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:Next wakeup is due at 2011-10-06 18:30:33 (in 10.441128 seconds)

**With python-daemon,**
Output is blank. Why isn't the DaemonContext correctly spawning the processes?

**EDIT - Working**

After reading python-daemon source, I've added stdout and stderr to the DaemonContext and finally was able to know what was going on.

```
def job_function():
    print "Hello World"
    print >> test_log, "Hello World"

def init_schedule():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    sched = Scheduler()
    sched.start()

    return sched

def schedule_job(sched, function, periodicity, start_time):
    sched.add_interval_job(job_function, seconds=periodicity, start_date=start_time)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    test_log = open('daemon.log', 'w')
    daemon.DaemonContext.files_preserve = [test_log]

    try:
           with daemon.DaemonContext():
                   from datetime import datetime
                   from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
                   import signal

                   logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
                   sched = init_schedule()

                   schedule_job(sched, job_function, 120, '2011-10-06 12:30:09')
                   schedule_job(sched, job_function, 120, '2011-10-06 12:31:03')

                   signal.pause()

    except Exception, e:
           print e
```

Comment: I have a simple cron replacements in Python. It's available [here](https://github.com/nibrahim/openlibrary/blob/master/openlibrary/core/minicron.py) and  the entry point script is [here](https://github.com/nibrahim/openlibrary/blob/master/scripts/minicron.py) if you want to give it a shot. I haven't found the time to refactor it out into a separate app yet.

Comment: I'd welcome your feedback. I should really put it out as a separate package.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about python-daemon, but `test_log` in `job_function()` is not defined. The same problem occurs in `init_schedule()` where you reference `Schedule`.

Comment: rocksportsrocker, test_log is defined in __main__ I've previously tried running it and the Python interpreter didn't complain. I'm importing Scheduler inside the daemon.DaemonContext, it seemed to me the right thing to do, given that when the daemon forks, any open sockets or files are forced to close.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've added a sample output. On the 2nd case, the output is blank and the test.log isn't written. The goal is that a daemon pid is spawned and the tasks keep running indefinitely.

Comment: Can you introduce debug logging in the with-context ? Just to see what is executed and what not...

Comment: I've both added debug logging and stdout,stderr to the DaemonContext and finally got it working.(added an EDIT to the question). Thanks for the patience !

Comment: Was forgetting to pass 'sched' object to the schedule_job call, before editing I had: schedule_job(job_function, 120, '2011-10-06 12:30:09')
This would be usually get caught by the try/except construct, but DaemonContext was masking it, hiding all output.